# SQL sum from union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables I'm unioning together and I would like to sum the values instead of having 2 different rows with the same ID. This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
    d.ID,
    SUM(d.balance) AS Balance
FROM  
    d
WHERE 
    d.status != 'closed'
GROUP BY 
    d.ID

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t.ID,
    SUM(t.balance) AS Balance
FROM 
    t
WHERE 
    t.status != 'closed'
GROUP BY 
    t.ID
```

This gives me a list with all the d values, then all the t values, I would like any rows with matching IDs to all be in one row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an outer query around your current query and group by again as follows:

```
select id, sum(Balance)
from (
  SELECT d.ID, SUM(d.balance) AS Balance
  FROM d
  WHERE d.[status] != 'closed'
  GROUP BY d.ID

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.ID, SUM(t.balance) AS Balance
  FROM t
  WHERE t.[status] != 'closed'
  GROUP BY t.ID
) X
group by id
```

in fact don't really need the inner `group by`'s, so the following should still work and be clearer:

```
select id, sum(Balance)
from (
  SELECT d.ID, d.balance
  FROM d
  WHERE d.[status] != 'closed'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.ID, t.balance
  FROM t
  WHERE t.[status] != 'closed'
) X
group by id
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope  this will help you

```
  DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [id] INT
   ,[Balance] Float
   ,status Varchar(50)

);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Balance],[Status])
VALUES (1, 100 ,'Closed')
      ,(2, 200,'Open' )
      ,(3, 300 ,'Onhold')
      ,(4, 400 ,'Open')


DECLARE @DataSource1 TABLE
(
   [id] INT
   ,[Balance] Float
  ,status Varchar(50)

);


INSERT INTO @DataSource1 ([ID], [Balance],[Status])
VALUES (1, 3 ,'Open')
      ,(2, 3 ,'Open')
      ,(3, 55 ,'Onhold')
      ,(4, 6 ,'Closed')


      SELECT d.ID,sum((Case When d.status!='Closed' Then d.Balance Else 0 End )+(Case When t.status!='Closed' Then t.Balance Else 0 End))
      FROM @DataSource d
     inner Join  @DataSource1 t
     on t.ID= d.ID
     Group By  d.ID,  t.ID


enter code here
```

Comment: That doesn't provide an answer to the question asked.

Comment: I edited answer  @Dale Burrell. It  give the same Result.